Bluetooth not discovering devices, driver current (Kubuntu 24.04)
New to Kubuntu (24.04) this week and trying to get everything set up, I found that bluetooth is not detecting any devices (I have tried with several devices in pairing mode that work on other OS and with my Android phone).  I have found how to check the status of the bluetooth service, get information for my device, and everything seems to  be healthy and with correct drivers, but I'm not able to discover any devices.  Any suggestions about what to try would be greatly appreciated.
Here is the output that makes me think bluetooth service and device are up and running...
codys@lilKalu:~$ service bluetooth status
● bluetooth.service - Bluetooth service
     Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/bluetooth.service; enabled; preset: enabled)
     Active: active (running) since Sun 2024-06-16 09:41:07 CDT; 17min ago
       Docs: man:bluetoothd(8)
   Main PID: 869 (bluetoothd)
     Status: "Running"
      Tasks: 1 (limit: 18647)
     Memory: 3.1M (peak: 4.0M)
        CPU: 84ms
     CGroup: /system.slice/bluetooth.service
             └─869 /usr/libexec/bluetooth/bluetoothd

Jun 16 09:41:14 lilKalu bluetoothd[869]: Endpoint registered: sender=:1.54 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSource/aptx_ll_1
Jun 16 09:41:14 lilKalu bluetoothd[869]: Endpoint registered: sender=:1.54 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSource/aptx_ll_0
Jun 16 09:41:14 lilKalu bluetoothd[869]: Endpoint registered: sender=:1.54 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSource/aptx_ll_duplex_1
Jun 16 09:41:14 lilKalu bluetoothd[869]: Endpoint registered: sender=:1.54 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSource/aptx_ll_duplex_0
Jun 16 09:41:14 lilKalu bluetoothd[869]: Endpoint registered: sender=:1.54 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSource/faststream
Jun 16 09:41:14 lilKalu bluetoothd[869]: Endpoint registered: sender=:1.54 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSource/faststream_duplex
Jun 16 09:41:14 lilKalu bluetoothd[869]: Endpoint registered: sender=:1.54 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSink/opus_05
Jun 16 09:41:14 lilKalu bluetoothd[869]: Endpoint registered: sender=:1.54 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSource/opus_05
Jun 16 09:41:14 lilKalu bluetoothd[869]: Endpoint registered: sender=:1.54 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSink/opus_05_duplex
Jun 16 09:41:14 lilKalu bluetoothd[869]: Endpoint registered: sender=:1.54 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSource/opus_05_duplex

codys@lilKalu:~$ hciconfig
hci0:   Type: Primary  Bus: USB
        BD Address: E8:65:38:29:C4:04  ACL MTU: 1021:8  SCO MTU: 255:12
        UP RUNNING 
        RX bytes:1459 acl:0 sco:0 events:174 errors:0
        TX bytes:7219 acl:0 sco:0 commands:162 errors:0


codys@lilKalu:~$ bluetoothctl
Waiting to connect to bluetoothd...[bluetooth]# Agent registered
[bluetooth]# power on
[bluetooth]# Changing power on succeeded
[bluetooth]# scan on
[bluetooth]# SetDiscoveryFilter success
[bluetooth]# Discovery started
[bluetooth]# [CHG] Controller E8:65:38:29:C4:04 Discovering: yes
[bluetooth]# 


But in this tutorial at this step, their bluetooth starts discovering devices and mine does not.  It also does not discover any devices with the built-in bluetooth GUI, or with blueman.
Output of sudo dmesg | grep -i 'blue':
[    2.113319] usb 1-10: Product: Bluetooth Radio
[    2.941515] Bluetooth: Core ver 2.22
[    2.941734] NET: Registered PF_BLUETOOTH protocol family
[    2.941737] Bluetooth: HCI device and connection manager initialized
[    2.941742] Bluetooth: HCI socket layer initialized
[    2.941744] Bluetooth: L2CAP socket layer initialized
[    2.941750] Bluetooth: SCO socket layer initialized
[    4.083360] Bluetooth: BNEP (Ethernet Emulation) ver 1.3
[    4.083364] Bluetooth: BNEP filters: protocol multicast
[    4.083369] Bluetooth: BNEP socket layer initialized
[    4.085207] Bluetooth: MGMT ver 1.22
[    6.504663] Bluetooth: RFCOMM TTY layer initialized
[    6.504674] Bluetooth: RFCOMM socket layer initialized
[    6.504683] Bluetooth: RFCOMM ver 1.11

Output of uname -a; lspci -nnk | grep -iA2 net; lsusb | grep -i 'blue'; sudo dmesg | grep -i firmware; lsmod | grep bluetooth:
Linux lilKalu 6.8.0-35-generic #35-Ubuntu SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Mon May 20 15:51:52 UTC 2024 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
0000:01:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. Device [10ec:b851]
        Subsystem: Foxconn International, Inc. Device [105b:e100]
        Kernel driver in use: rtw89_8851be
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 0489:e112 Foxconn / Hon Hai Bluetooth Radio
[    3.622527] rtw89_8851be 0000:01:00.0: loaded firmware rtw89/rtw8851b_fw.bin
[    3.626746] rtw89_8851be 0000:01:00.0: Firmware version 0.29.41.3 (65cefb31), cmd version 0, type 5
[    3.626758] rtw89_8851be 0000:01:00.0: Firmware version 0.29.41.3 (65cefb31), cmd version 0, type 3
bluetooth            1032192  44 btrtl,btmtk,btintel,btbcm,bnep,btusb,rfcomm
ecdh_generic           16384  2 bluetooth

And output of just lspci -nnk | grep -iA2 net  since that was asked for specifically in similar questions:
0000:01:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. Device [10ec:b851]
        Subsystem: Foxconn International, Inc. Device [105b:e100]
        Kernel driver in use: rtw89_8851be

To me, this looks like the device is working, discovered, has drivers, and is properly connected to the bluetooth service, and I know it works from testing it in Windows on this machine, but something is keeping it from discovering any devices.  Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!
(note: I don't know if this is relevant but as mentioned this system is dual-booting with Windows.  I already disabled Fast Boot in Windows as part of troubleshooting for a wifi issue.)

In terminal check mokutil --sb as Secure Boot has to be disabled as this kernel module will not be signed.
Then in terminal
sudo apt install git dkms
git clone https://github.com/jeremyb31/bluetooth-6.8.git
sudo dkms add ./bluetooth-6.8
sudo dkms install btusb/4.1
Reboot
I added the following code to btusb source code in kernel 6.8
https://github.com/jeremyb31/bluetooth-6.8/commit/0f3b823eea66adf1fbabc865f89484ea486f6e65

codys@lilKalu:~$ mokutil --sb SecureBoot disabled

This worked for getting my device to see other Bluetooth devices, thank you so much!
Speakers sound not very clear, like a phone call... is that a separate question. or is that related to this issue?

Check Sound Settings, it is likely set to HSP/HFP profile rather than A2DP which is stereo high quality

I found that in some other answers, but I'm not able to change the bluetooth profile, and I'm not seeing A2DP anywhere. I'm not sure I have that profile to choose from, is there something else I need to do to enable/install it?  Is there a better way for me to find these things on my own than looking through old AskUbuntu answers?
